# libcurl how to stop redirecting when an url redirect to itself

Tags: c++, redirect, libcurl

I use libcurl to get webpage's source code, everything goes all right until to get the source code of "www.macys.com".

My programme gets nothing without CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION option, but when with this option, the redirecting location is always '/' and the curl_easy_perform function will not return unless I set the CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS option.

My question is how can I get this webpage's source code with libcurl ? 
Thanks a lot.

My libcurl version : 7.23.1,  OS: CentOS 6.0（final) x64

Comment: Would probably help to have your current source code to see where you are going wrong. Otherwise you're basically asking someone to code the solution for you!

Answer (score 0):

If the server keeps redirecting the client, and you ask the client to follow the redirects then what are you expecting it to do?

The only option is to stop after a certain amount of steps, which is what CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS is used for.

The reason things like this happens is mostly because the site is checking for client specific details (user-agent, cookies, referer or similar) that your curl use doesn't provide. You can often make your curl requests more similar to a browser's and then avoid this effect.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your advice, my problem is solved after making my curl requests as same as a browser's.

Answer (score 0):

Either disable CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION and manually keep track of redirections to ensure a loop does not happen or set CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS to an insane number (10) which can only be reached via self-redirects.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, my problem is solved after making my curl requests as same as a browser's, it seems that this website is stricter  with it.